# Golang How can I keep my SQL queries out of my code?

Tags: sql, go

I'm stuck on trying to decide the best way to organize sql queries, and code.

Right now I have a `models/` folder in my package which contains all my tables, each in their own `.go` file, which contains a struct that matches the database table.

I've been making a mess of my code though by throwing a ton of sqlQueries into it, especially with  transactions and what not.

How exactly can I structure my code, without littering it with SQL queries.

(I don't want to use an ORM to accomplish this)

Comment: https://github.com/mattermost/platform Separate as store and model as they are doing here.

Comment: How about using stored procedures? Inline SQL is considered very bad practice in general, not just for code clarity reasons but also because you don't protect yourself from SQL injection when you're using things like `fm.Sprintf` to form your query string. Also check out `Prepare` in the sql package, it returns a `*Stmt` which you can reuse as much as you'd like.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/nleof/goyesql: Parse a file and associate SQL queries to a map. Useful for separating SQL from code logic.

Comment: You can also have a look to drone repository implementation: https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/master/store/datastore/agents.go

Comment: This isn't specifically a golang problem.  But there are extensions that exist that might help such as Sqlx:  https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

Comment: I confirm, what you really need is a "repository pattern". Leave your model simple, and introduce a classes that deal with interfacing business needs with DB. https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC340233.png

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something that looks like a [data mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

**Example from the EAA catalog:**

[image]

**In Go:**

model/person.go

```
type Person struct {
  Lastname   string
  Firstname  string
  Dependents int
}
```

mapper/person.go

```
package mapper

import m "whatever/model"

type PersonMap struct { }

func (m *PersonMap) Insert(p *m.Person) error {
  // SQL query
  return nil
}

func (m *PersonMap) Update(p *m.Person) error {
  // SQL query
  return nil
}

func (m *PersonMap) Delete(p *m.Person) error {
  // SQL query
  return nil
}
```

However, that solution would only be a part of the solution. Regarding the DB transactions, I think you should manage them from another "layer".